# How to prevent 'Default' group in ObjectListView after ModelDropped event?

Tags: c#, vb.net, drag-and-drop, objectlistview

I'm trying to create a rearrangeable list of stops along routes in ObjectListView. My list is grouped and sorted correctly upon initialization. See link below:

Routes after initialization, correctly grouped

[image]

When I drag and drop a row(regardless if dropped in the same group or a different group), it gets moved into a new 'Default' group. See below:

Routes after drag & drop, with Rt 2, Stop 4 moved into 'Default' group

[image]

I've tried various attempts at refreshing and resorting to no avail. Can someone explain why this being grouped into 'Default' and how to fix? Thanks!

Here is my code in its entirety:

```
private void RouteEditor_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Stop stop1 = new Stop();
    stop1 .Customer = "Test4";
    stop1 .Location = "10010";
    stop1 .Weight = 13;
    stop1 .StopNumber = 4;
    stop1 .Route = "Route 2";
    StopList.Add(stop1 );

    this.objectListView1.SetObjects(StopList);

    this.objectListView1.DragSource = new BrightIdeasSoftware.SimpleDragSource();
    this.objectListView1.DropSink = new BrightIdeasSoftware.RearrangingDropSink(false);      
}

private void objectListView1_ModelCanDrop(object sender, BrightIdeasSoftware.ModelDropEventArgs e)
{
    e.DropSink.CanDropBetween = true;
    e.DropSink.CanDropOnItem = false;

    if (e.TargetModel == null)
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
    else
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
}

private void objectListView1_ModelDropped(object sender, BrightIdeasSoftware.ModelDropEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.TargetModel == null)
        return;

    Stop targetStop = e.TargetModel as Stop;
    foreach (Stop s in e.SourceModels)
        s.Route = targetStop.Route;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the "Default" group mechanism. Maybe the OLV just does not know what to do with the dropped item, because its not re-evaluating / re-building the groups after each drop.

[From the manual](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/dragdrop.html#rearranging-rows-by-dragging):

> Example: if the control is grouping students by academic grade, and the user drags a “Fail” grade student into the “A+” group, it is the responsibility of the programmer to makes the appropriate changes to the model and redraw/rebuild the control so that the users action makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was asked a long time ago but for anyone else with the same problem here is the solution I found worked for me.

After reading some discussions in the Objectlistview forum I found that the RearrangingDropSink class does not work with grouped Objectlistviews so I switched to using a SimpleDropSink object and it worked, no more 'Default' group - the dropped item is dropped in the expected place within a group.

So, for the example in the question, change:

```
this.objectListView1.DropSink = new BrightIdeasSoftware.RearrangingDropSink(false);
```

to

```
this.objectListView1.DropSink = new BrightIdeasSoftware.SimpleDropSink();
this.objectListView1.DropSink.CanDropOnItem = false;
```